# Cannot see dropdown options with React MUI while using the Autocomplete Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Hi I am trying to create an autocomplete component with a proper dropdown but I am unable to see any of my dropdown options populating when I click on the text field.

```
    <Autocomplete
    id='demo-1'
    style={{height:'30px', margin:'14px 0px', width: '362px', padding: '2px', fontSize: 'small' }}
    options={myData.map(option=>option.desc)}
    size='small'
    disableClearable
    multiple
    onChange={(e, data) => setSelectedSource(data)}
    renderOption={(props, option) => (
    <li {...props}>
    <Checkbox
    className={classes.checkBoxClass}
    checked={selectedSource.includes(option)}
    onChange={() => {}}
    />
    {option.desc}
    </li>
    )
    }
renderInput = {(params) => (
<TextField {...params}
variant='outlined'
placeholder='select options'
InputLabelProps={{ ...params.InputLabelProps }}
/>
)}
/>
```

I think I am maybe messing up the options but I am not 100% sure, not sure what I am missing here.

Thanks.

Comment: From the doc:
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#options-structure
Your options should have a structure like this:
    `{ label: 'label', value: 'myvalue' }`
(you also need to change it in your item render function)

Comment: @FlorianWalch how would I change my item render function exactly?